# Stored Procedure For a User table, to get age and name using sql server 2014

Tags: sql

I have a single table, User table, with three columns ( id, name and age). How do i create a stored procedure to get the names and ages alone?

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetName 
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT Name,Age
     FROM User
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserDetails  
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT Name, Age from User 
END
GO
```